# xcode : storyboard does not reflect changes made in code in ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development.

When I create anything in the ViewController.swift file (UITextField or UILable etc) it doesn't show on the main.storyboard (or the storyboard preview)

[this is what the storyboard looks next to the simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2q0B.png)

The simulation Is exactly what I want it to look like but its totally different than the storyboard

I have created a UITextField using the AutoLayout and I have connected it via outlet in the code and edited it looks like so :

[the code in ViewController.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2MgP.png)

I just want the storyboard to reflect the changes I've made in the code and look just like the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storyboard won't run your VC's code each time it loads, so there's no way to make your code written in a VC have an effect on the storyboard.

What you *can* do however, is to make a custom view.

In this case, you want your text field to look different on the storyboard, so try creating a `UITextField` subclass. If you then set the text field's custom class in the storyboard to your custom subclass, it will look the way you wanted.

Here's how you do this:

```
@IBDesignable // this is important as it tells IB that it should draw this view in the storyboard
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override func draw(in rect: CGRect) {
        // configure how you want the text field to look here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but can you explain a bit more how exactly to do this. When I add the code snippet you wrote first it needs to replace "in" with an underscore and then I can't connect it to the UITextField in the storyboard. Im just not sure I understand what I have to do properly.

Comment: @Nox you just need to provide text field class to your storyboard text field.

Comment: @TusharSharma [link](http://i.imgur.com/RDwNezp.png) I add it there but it still doesn't change. Can you give me and example of what the code inside the override function might look like. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard does not reflect the changes in development mode, it will reflect only at Run-Time.

Instead of writing code in UIViewController class, you can create a custom UITextField class. Here is the code:-

import UIKit

class NameField: UITextField {

```
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    self.autocorrectionType = .no
    self.keyboardType = .default
    self.returnKeyType = .default
    self.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    self.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
    self.borderStyle = .none


    // Set UITextField Border Layer

    let layer = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    layer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.frame.height-width, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)

    layer.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

}
```

}

Once, you have created a custom UITextField class then in storyboard assign it's name to your UITextFiled and run the Application. You will find an effect of code as you want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hQnL.png)

Hope, this would help you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your in depth explanation it works perfectly now

Comment: Your Wellcome @Nox